# Downloading a div on a pdf file with jsPDF : text get cut instead of changing page (Firefox/IE)

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

I have a file with a div and 2 buttons: one to print the div, the other one to download it as pdf.

The printing function works perfectly but the downloading function has some problems : 
I use jsPDF ([included from here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js))
and it works fine when my content can fit in one page, but if it needs more than one page, it won't write on other pages (but the number of page generated is correct though).

**EDIT :** Tested with :

- Google Chrome 66.0 : works perfectly
- Firefox 59.0.3 : not working
- Internet Explorer 11.0 : not working

(Obviously the company works only with Firefox and IE o/ )

Here's my code :

**EDIT :** [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/cesrcfr2/)

/!\ There's an error if you try running the snippet on SO.

```js
    var specialElementHandlers = {
      '#editor': function(element, renderer) {
        return true;
      }
    };

    $('#generatePDF').click(function() {
      var pdf = new jsPDF();
      pdf.fromHTML($('#myDivToPrint').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers,
        'pagesplit': true
      });
      pdf.save('file_generated.pdf');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDivToPrint" id="myDivToPrint">
  Devis : 1200€ TTC

  <ul>
    <li>Phasellus a odio vitae tortor mattis sodales malesuada ut orci.</li>
    <li>Maecenas laoreet, nisl quis gravida ullamcorper.</li>
    <li>ipsum tortor semper diam, non lacinia ipsum lorem id orci.</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>Aliquam malesuada velit at pharetra pellentesque.</li>
    <li>Nunc id varius nisi.</li>
    <li>Mauris posuere a nisl nec rutrum.</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>Vestibulum hendrerit magna sed felis rhoncus.</li>
    <li>vitae pharetra ex sagittis.</li>
    <li>Nunc bibendum ultrices nibh a tempus.</li>
    <li>Proin ultrices ipsum non posuere blandit.</li>
    <li>In imperdiet, orci non mattis commodo.</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>libero risus tristique mi, eget vehicula felis ante et turpis.</li>
    <li>Mauris elementum mi elit.</li>
    <li>Maecenas nec justo eget leo laoreet auctor vel quis odio.</li>
    <li>Morbi eget scelerisque risus.</li>
    <li>tincidunt aliquet nulla.</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>Quisque eget lectus vel elit dictum varius vitae non arcu.</li>
    <li>Donec elementum lorem quis finibus varius.</li>
    <li>Suspendisse id erat vel purus egestas finibus at sed lorem.</li>
    <li>Ut auctor erat quis magna consectetur, id sollicitudin sapien elementum.</li>
    <li>Fusce placerat turpis eu efficitur cursus.</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>Vestibulum hendrerit magna sed felis rhoncus.</li>
    <li>vitae pharetra ex sagittis.</li>
    <li>Nunc bibendum ultrices nibh a tempus.</li>
    <li>Proin ultrices ipsum non posuere blandit.</li>
    <li>In imperdiet, orci non mattis commodo.</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>libero risus tristique mi, eget vehicula felis ante et turpis.</li>
    <li>Mauris elementum mi elit.</li>
    <li>Maecenas nec justo eget leo laoreet auctor vel quis odio.</li>
    <li>Morbi eget scelerisque risus.</li>
    <li>tincidunt aliquet nulla.</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>Quisque eget lectus vel elit dictum varius vitae non arcu.</li>
    <li>Donec elementum lorem quis finibus varius.</li>
    <li>Suspendisse id erat vel purus egestas finibus at sed lorem.</li>
    <li>Ut auctor erat quis magna consectetur, id sollicitudin sapien elementum.</li>
    <li>Fusce placerat turpis eu efficitur cursus.</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>libero risus tristique mi, eget vehicula felis ante et turpis.</li>
    <li>Mauris elementum mi elit.</li>
    <li>Maecenas nec justo eget leo laoreet auctor vel quis odio.</li>
    <li>Morbi eget scelerisque risus.</li>
    <li>tincidunt aliquet nulla.</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>Quisque eget lectus vel elit dictum varius vitae non arcu.</li>
    <li>Donec elementum lorem quis finibus varius.</li>
    <li>Suspendisse id erat vel purus egestas finibus at sed lorem.</li>
    <li>Ut auctor erat quis magna consectetur, id sollicitudin sapien elementum.</li>
    <li>Fusce placerat turpis eu efficitur cursus.</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>Vestibulum hendrerit magna sed felis rhoncus.</li>
    <li>vitae pharetra ex sagittis.</li>
    <li>Nunc bibendum ultrices nibh a tempus.</li>
    <li>Proin ultrices ipsum non posuere blandit.</li>
    <li>In imperdiet, orci non mattis commodo.</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>libero risus tristique mi, eget vehicula felis ante et turpis.</li>
    <li>Mauris elementum mi elit.</li>
    <li>Maecenas nec justo eget leo laoreet auctor vel quis odio.</li>
    <li>Morbi eget scelerisque risus.</li>
    <li>tincidunt aliquet nulla.</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>Quisque eget lectus vel elit dictum varius vitae non arcu.</li>
    <li>Donec elementum lorem quis finibus varius.</li>
    <li>Suspendisse id erat vel purus egestas finibus at sed lorem.</li>
    <li>Ut auctor erat quis magna consectetur, id sollicitudin sapien elementum.</li>
    <li>Fusce placerat turpis eu efficitur cursus.</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>libero risus tristique mi, eget vehicula felis ante et turpis.</li>
    <li>Mauris elementum mi elit.</li>
    <li>Maecenas nec justo eget leo laoreet auctor vel quis odio.</li>
    <li>Morbi eget scelerisque risus.</li>
    <li>tincidunt aliquet nulla.</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>Quisque eget lectus vel elit dictum varius vitae non arcu.</li>
    <li>Donec elementum lorem quis finibus varius.</li>
    <li>Suspendisse id erat vel purus egestas finibus at sed lorem.</li>
    <li>Ut auctor erat quis magna consectetur, id sollicitudin sapien elementum.</li>
    <li>Fusce placerat turpis eu efficitur cursus.</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>Vestibulum hendrerit magna sed felis rhoncus.</li>
    <li>vitae pharetra ex sagittis.</li>
    <li>Nunc bibendum ultrices nibh a tempus.</li>
    <li>Proin ultrices ipsum non posuere blandit.</li>
    <li>In imperdiet, orci non mattis commodo.</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>libero risus tristique mi, eget vehicula felis ante et turpis.</li>
    <li>Mauris elementum mi elit.</li>
    <li>Maecenas nec justo eget leo laoreet auctor vel quis odio.</li>
    <li>Morbi eget scelerisque risus.</li>
    <li>tincidunt aliquet nulla.</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>Quisque eget lectus vel elit dictum varius vitae non arcu.</li>
    <li>Donec elementum lorem quis finibus varius.</li>
    <li>Suspendisse id erat vel purus egestas finibus at sed lorem.</li>
    <li>Ut auctor erat quis magna consectetur, id sollicitudin sapien elementum.</li>
    <li>Fusce placerat turpis eu efficitur cursus.</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>Vestibulum hendrerit manga sed felis rhoncus.</li>
    <li>vitae pharetra ex sagittis.</li>
    <li>Nunc bibendum ultrices nibh a tempus.</li>
    <li>Proin ultrices ipsum non posuere blandit.</li>
    <li>In imperdiet, orci non mattis commodo.</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>libero risus tristique mi, eget vehicula felis ante et turpis.</li>
    <li>Mauris elementum mi elit.</li>
    <li>Maecenas nec justo eget leo laoreet auctor vel quis odio.</li>
    <li>Morbi eget scelerisque risus.</li>
    <li>tincidunt aliquet nulla.</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>Quisque eget lectus vel elit dictum varius vitae non arcu.</li>
    <li>Donec elementum lorem quis finibus varius.</li>
    <li>Suspendisse id erat vel purus egestas finibus at sed lorem.</li>
    <li>Ut auctor erat quis magna consectetur, id sollicitudin sapien elementum.</li>
    <li>Fusce placerat turpis eu efficitur cursus.</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>libero risus tristique mi, eget vehicula felis ante et turpis.</li>
    <li>Mauris elementum mi elit.</li>
    <li>Maecenas nec justo eget leo laoreet auctor vel quis odio.</li>
    <li>Morbi eget scelerisque risus.</li>
    <li>tincidunt aliquet nulla.</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="editor"></div>
</div>

<div class="contenuCentreTPC">
  <button class="button-blue" id="generatePDF">Télécharger</button>
</div>
```

The button works perfectly, but when I reach the end of the first page, an alert box warns me this pdf contains an error and the next pages are blank :

[image: End of 1st page]

Do you know what causes this error ? And how to fix it ?

Thanks for reading !

Comment: I fixed your snippet, but it seems not to be allowed to run

Comment: Yep, tried to make the snippet works as well, looks like it doesn't like jsPDF :/

EDIT : Put the script inside the html, now something is happening when you click

Comment: No difference. It is the sandbox here at SO

Comment: Edit : added a jsfiddle link, runs perfectly (with the original problem though)

Comment: Works fine in Chrome

Comment: Just tested in Chrome, works indeed. 
Tried again with Firefox and Internet Explorer, still the same problem, compatibility issues I suppose ?

Comment: I guess so. Firefox has its own version of JSPdf

Comment: Never heard of it and didn't managed to find a "jspdf firefox version" on google, do you have a link please ?

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/view-pdf-files-firefox#w_using-the-built-in-pdf-viewer

Comment: I'll see what I can do with this !
Thanks for helping me !